# List all Cucumber scenarios without associated tests

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I inherited a large body of Cucumber tests and I'd like to quickly see which scenarios are missing tests (i.e., those for which a run produces a `Pending...` result.

Failing that, how can I list all the scenarios in a given project? The standard `cucumber -d` fails because it attempts to parse `step_definition` files as features.

Comment: I think your situation is more complicated than you have revealed in your question. Can you provide more information? When you say 'tests', do you mean step definitions or scenarios?

Comment: @Dave McNulla For clarity - I was interested in seeing which scenarios do not have defined step definitions, so I could delete them. I did this in a thankless manual way with awk - would still be interested in a general solution to "how to indicate pending status on scenarios". Maybe "show result of most recent run on scenario".